# Nest js passport AuthGuard not verifying a valid token - returns "401 Unauthorized" or "Invalid signature"

Tags: authentication, jwt, nestjs, authorization, passport.js

Token generation with local strategy works and the token are verifiable with JwtService `validate(token)` but not when using `@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))`

This works:

```js
// auth.controller.ts
// ...
  @Post(`/verify`)
  async verify(@Request() req, @Headers() headers) {
    const authHeader = headers['authorization'] // manually get the Authorization header value
    const token = authHeader.substring('Bearer '.length) // This will remove the Bearer prefix
    return this.jwtService.verify(token)
  }
```

This doesn't:

```js
// auth.controller.ts
// ...
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  @Post(`/verify`)
  async verify(@Request() req, @Headers() headers) {
    return(req.user)
  }
```

The secret is properly set in jwt strategy configs

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport'
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt'

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: `${process.env.JWT_SECRET}`,
    })
  }

  async validate(username: string, password: string) {
    return { username, password }
  }
}
```

and in the module

```js
// auth.module.ts
// ...

@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: User.name,
        schema: UserSchema,
      },
    ]),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: `${process.env.JWT_SECRET}`,
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: '60d',
      },
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    UserService,
    HashService,
    LocalStrategy,
    JwtStrategy,
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Finally, when trying to handle with a custom `@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)` instead of `@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))` I can read the token correctly in `canActivate()` but `handleRequest()`  (still) returns anauthorized and reveals 'Jsonwebtokenerror: Invalid Signature' in logs

```js
// jwt-gaurd.ts
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport'
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt'

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  constructor(private jwtService: JwtService) {
    super({
      secret: `${process.env.JWT_SECRET}`,
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: '60d',
      },
    })
  }

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest()
    const token = request.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
    try {
      const payload = await this.jwtService.verify(token)
      console.log(payload) // logs correctly
      super.canActivate(context)
      return true
    } catch (error) {
      return false
    }
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    return payload
  }

  handleRequest(err, user, info) {
    console.log(err, user, info)
    if (err || !user) {
      return err
    }
    return user
  }
}
```

As shown above I tried extracting the token in multiple places and it correctly verifies and gets the payload.

I made sure that my imports are aligned with existing threads about the error and logged the secret to make sure it is correct everywhere.

No idea why everything can work as expected except the guard decorators. Any help would be of great value to my sanity.

Answer (score 1):

This is what finally worked for me, [Nest docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#implementing-the-authentication-guard) now recommends extending CanActivate and NOT AuthGuard('jwt') for guarding endpoints

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found a solution for my specific case.
The problem is `jwt.sign(token)` did not sign using the secret supplied from the Module.

Try to first verify by generating a jwt token from jwt.io (with your SECRET_TOKEN) and then feed it to your service. If that works -> your `jwt.verify()` is at least working properly.

Then try to generate jwt token from your service by calling `jwt.sign(token, {secret: SECRET_TOKEN})`. Validate the signed token in jwt.io and through your service.

On a side note, the AuthGuard below work and using it will eliminate the use of the strategy:

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private svc: AuthService) { }
    
  private extractToken(request: Request): string | undefined {
    const cookieToken = request.signedCookies ? request.signedCookies['token'] : null;
    if (cookieToken) {
      return cookieToken;
    }
    const [type, headerToken] = request.headers.authorization?.split(' ') ?? [];
    return type === 'Bearer' ? headerToken : undefined;
  }

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const token = this.extractToken(request);
    if (!token) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    try {
      const payload = this.svc.verifyJwtToken(token);
      request['user'] = payload;
    } catch(err) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```